# I cant connect to a sql server from remote network

Tags: java, sql-server, dns, odbc, infrastructure

I had point A where I need to run the program, the point C where is the sql server, and the point B where we use to work with sql managment, there we connect with point C. But I can't reach point C from point A, so an option was to use ODBC, but after java 8 version, use ODBC is some kind of difficult. There a easy way to use the odbc, or connect from point A to point C using the B like bridge?

Comment: Is the firewall opened up between A and C?  Are you only allowing connections to C from specific IP's?

Comment: Is it a development environment where workaround are permitted or are you in a production environment?

Comment: We can allow to connect from A to C for securities reasons. And yes, it is a production environment.